# Android splash Activity does not implement or extend Thread Class

Tags: android

The splash screen activity works on thread class but it does not extend or implement Thread. then how does the Thread work inside the Activity?

Comment: can do using inner/ anonymous class....

Comment: It can, just dont call stop (thread api).

Answer (score 1):

Why Activity not extends `Thread class`.you can implements `Runnable` as in your `Activity`:

```
public class AndroidRunnable extends Activity implements Runnable{

Thread myThread;


  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  @Override
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

See this Example for Creating Splashing Screen Activity Using Thread:

[Android tutorial: How to make a basic splash screen](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-basic-splash-screen/)